# Get variable to pass to php form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on getting the following block of code to send the array variable 'row' to another page. The other page should pull the vendor_id from this array and help populate a form with database information. I'm completely lost at how to accomplish this as I am relatively new to web dev. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
  function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [

      '<a class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
      '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
      '</a>',
      '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php" title="View">',
      '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
      '</a>'
    ].join('')
  }

  window.operateEvents = {
    'click .view': function (e, value, row, index) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("vendor_id", JSON.stringify(row));

    },
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: [row.id]
      })
    }
  }
```

viewVendor.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
require './db_inc.php';


$user = $_SESSION['username'];




## Fetch records
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vendor_data");


$stmt->execute();
$Records = $stmt->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($Records as $row){
   $data[] = array(

      "name"=>$row['name'],
      "company"=>$row['company'],
      "type"=>$row['type'],
      "status"=>$row['status'],
      "owner"=>$row['owner'],
      "descr"=>$row['descr'],
      "owner_email"=>$row['owner_email'],
      "dept"=>$row['dept']
   );
}


return json_encode(($data));
?>
<script>
alert(sessionStorage.getItem("vendor_id[1]"));
</script>
```

I have a php page that includes the above mentioned viewVendor.php file which should pass along the information. Maybe I'm over complicating things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the vendor_id to the query string in your a tag like (assuming 'row' is the vendor id value):

```
'<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row + '" title="View">',
```

Then in your viewVendor.php file, access it with:

```
$_GET['vendor_id']
```

Though you may want to validate the vendor id in the PHP if it's going to be used to query your db.

Comment: it shows up in the URL as object Object. I think the row variable is actually an array.

Comment: Do you only need the vendor_id from that object? If so, use 'row.value_id' (or whatever the key is) in the example I gave. It would be useful if you shared what 'row' looked like.